# Opus codec bitrate scalability

Tags: encoding, opus

On the website of the Opus code, there is an example demonstrating [bitrate scalability](https://opus-codec.org/examples/#bitrate-scalability).  This example is intended to "demonstrates what happens when gradually varying the bitrate".

This feature makes sense to me.  For a file, like a podcast where there is a musical intro and outro, those could be of higher bitrate than the middle (and longest) part of the file, which is just speech.  Or, in streaming, the bitrate could possibly be varied based on network congestion.

However, I've never seen a demonstration of how to create such bitrate scalability; neither in the documentation of [libopus](https://opus-codec.org/docs/opus-tools/opusenc.html), nor in [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libopus).

I did an experiment where I split a podcast into three part.  The first and third parts I encoded to Opus at a high bitrate.  The second part I encoded in a low bitrate.  I then concatenated the files together using FFmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:1.opus|2.opus|3.opus" -c copy joined.opus
```

The file size is as expected (`|1.opus| + |2.opus| + |3.opus| ≈ |joined.opus|`).  The file plays fine, and I can see (using `mpv --term-status-msg='${audio-bitrate}'`) the bitrate drop and rise at the expected times.  However, this feels like a hack.  The bitrate change is sudden, and not "gradual", as claimed in the Opus example web page.  And I don't know how this would work for streaming.

What is the "correct" way of creating an Opus file with bitrate scalability?